# parsing xml using stax parser java

Tags: java

Hi I have a big xml file with multiple start tags please help me to parse it and display it based on group
my xml file will be

I want each user and content and conversation ID to be added to file  in one single line if different conversation ID then second line

for ex: output file should be 
 1 converID userName conversation + userName conversation ....
  2 anotherConvID userName conversation + userName conversation ....

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Data provided by Bloomberg LP. -->
<FileDump>
<Version>IBXML 1.3</Version>
<Conversation Perspective=" " RoomType="P">
<RoomID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</RoomID>
<StartTime>03/31/2016 13:39:01</StartTime>
<StartTimeUTC>1459431541</StartTimeUTC>
<ParticipantEntered InteractionType="N" DeviceType="M">
<User>
<LoginName>SWONG00</LoginName>
<FirstName>STEPHEN</FirstName>
<LastName>WONG</LastName>
<UUID>4397109</UUID>
<FirmNumber>13133</FirmNumber>
<AccountNumber>231115</AccountNumber>
<CompanyName>DBS BANK LIMITED HON</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>SWONG00@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress>STEPHENWONGWE@DBS.COM</CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>03/31/2016 13:39:01</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459431541</DateTimeUTC>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</ParticipantEntered>
<ParticipantEntered InteractionType="N" DeviceType="M">
<User>
<LoginName>G_LO</LoginName>
<FirstName>GARY</FirstName>
<LastName>LO</LastName>
<UUID>7054548</UUID>
<FirmNumber>13133</FirmNumber>
<AccountNumber>91189</AccountNumber>
<CompanyName>DBS BANK (HONG KONG)</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>G_LO@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress>garyloyc@dbs.com</CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>03/31/2016 14:56:22</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459436182</DateTimeUTC>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</ParticipantEntered>
<ParticipantLeft InteractionType="N" DeviceType="M">
<User>
<LoginName>G_LO</LoginName>
<FirstName>GARY</FirstName>
<LastName>LO</LastName>
<UUID>7054548</UUID>
<FirmNumber>13133</FirmNumber>
<AccountNumber>91189</AccountNumber>
<CompanyName>DBS BANK (HONG KONG)</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>G_LO@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress>garyloyc@dbs.com</CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>03/31/2016 19:30:01</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459452601</DateTimeUTC>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</ParticipantLeft>
<ParticipantLeft InteractionType="N" DeviceType="M">
<User>
<LoginName>SWONG00</LoginName>
<FirstName>STEPHEN</FirstName>
<LastName>WONG</LastName>
<UUID>4397109</UUID>
<FirmNumber>13133</FirmNumber>
<AccountNumber>231115</AccountNumber>
<CompanyName>DBS BANK LIMITED HON</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>SWONG00@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress>STEPHENWONGWE@DBS.COM</CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>03/31/2016 19:33:56</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459452836</DateTimeUTC>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</ParticipantLeft>
<ParticipantEntered InteractionType="N" DeviceType="M">
<User>
<LoginName>SWONG00</LoginName>
<FirstName>STEPHEN</FirstName>
<LastName>WONG</LastName>
<UUID>4397109</UUID>
<FirmNumber>13133</FirmNumber>
<AccountNumber>231115</AccountNumber>
<CompanyName>DBS BANK LIMITED HON</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>SWONG00@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress>STEPHENWONGWE@DBS.COM</CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>03/31/2016 19:45:16</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459453516</DateTimeUTC>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</ParticipantEntered>
<ParticipantLeft InteractionType="N" DeviceType="M">
<User>
<LoginName>SWONG00</LoginName>
<FirstName>STEPHEN</FirstName>
<LastName>WONG</LastName>
<UUID>4397109</UUID>
<FirmNumber>13133</FirmNumber>
<AccountNumber>231115</AccountNumber>
<CompanyName>DBS BANK LIMITED HON</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>SWONG00@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress>STEPHENWONGWE@DBS.COM</CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>03/31/2016 23:08:09</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459465689</DateTimeUTC>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</ParticipantLeft>
<ParticipantEntered InteractionType="N" DeviceType="M">
<User>
<LoginName>G_LO</LoginName>
<FirstName>GARY</FirstName>
<LastName>LO</LastName>
<UUID>7054548</UUID>
<FirmNumber>13133</FirmNumber>
<AccountNumber>91189</AccountNumber>
<CompanyName>DBS BANK (HONG KONG)</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>G_LO@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress>garyloyc@dbs.com</CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>03/31/2016 23:14:23</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459466063</DateTimeUTC>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</ParticipantEntered>
<Message InteractionType="N">
<User>
<LoginName>G_LO</LoginName>
<FirstName>GARY</FirstName>
<LastName>LO</LastName>
<UUID>7054548</UUID>
<FirmNumber>13133</FirmNumber>
<AccountNumber>91189</AccountNumber>
<CompanyName>DBS BANK (HONG KONG)</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>G_LO@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress>garyloyc@dbs.com</CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>04/01/2016 00:10:57</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459469457</DateTimeUTC>
<Content>
abcdefgghhhhhh
</Content>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</Message>
<ParticipantEntered InteractionType="N" DeviceType="M">
<User>
<LoginName>WVU</LoginName>
<FirstName>WHEELOCK</FirstName>
<LastName>VU</LastName>
<UUID>8266852</UUID>
<FirmNumber>13133</FirmNumber>
<AccountNumber>91189</AccountNumber>
<CompanyName>DBS BANK (HONG KONG)</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>WVU@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress>WHEELOCKVU@DBS.COM</CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>04/01/2016 00:14:05</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459469645</DateTimeUTC>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</ParticipantEntered>
<ParticipantEntered InteractionType="N">
<User>
<LoginName>FCHAN95</LoginName>
<FirstName>FLORENCE</FirstName>
<LastName>CHAN</LastName>
<CompanyName>GOLDMAN SACHS (ASIA)</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>FCHAN95@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress></CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>04/01/2016 00:29:19</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459470559</DateTimeUTC>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</ParticipantEntered>
<Message InteractionType="N">
<User>
<LoginName>FCHAN95</LoginName>
<FirstName>FLORENCE</FirstName>
<LastName>CHAN</LastName>
<CompanyName>GOLDMAN SACHS (ASIA)</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>FCHAN95@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress></CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>04/01/2016 00:29:19</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459470559</DateTimeUTC>
<Content>
ajdakjgdljsgdsafhkafa
</Content>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</Message>
<Message InteractionType="N">
<User>
<LoginName>FCHAN95</LoginName>
<FirstName>FLORENCE</FirstName>
<LastName>CHAN</LastName>
<CompanyName>GOLDMAN SACHS (ASIA)</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>FCHAN95@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress></CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>04/01/2016 00:29:19</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459470559</DateTimeUTC>
<Content>
akjdgljsafdlshf;kdsjf
</Content>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</Message>
<Message InteractionType="N">
<User>
<LoginName>WVU</LoginName>
<FirstName>WHEELOCK</FirstName>
<LastName>VU</LastName>
<UUID>8266852</UUID>
<FirmNumber>13133</FirmNumber>
<AccountNumber>91189</AccountNumber>
<CompanyName>DBS BANK (HONG KONG)</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>WVU@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress>WHEELOCKVU@DBS.COM</CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>04/01/2016 00:39:32</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459471172</DateTimeUTC>
<Content>
sagdksajdlsahd
</Content>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</Message>
<ParticipantEntered InteractionType="N" DeviceType="M">
<User>
<LoginName>SWONG00</LoginName>
<FirstName>STEPHEN</FirstName>
<LastName>WONG</LastName>
<UUID>4397109</UUID>
<FirmNumber>13133</FirmNumber>
<AccountNumber>231115</AccountNumber>
<CompanyName>DBS BANK LIMITED HON</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>SWONG00@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress>STEPHENWONGWE@DBS.COM</CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>04/01/2016 01:01:27</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459472487</DateTimeUTC>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</ParticipantEntered>
<Message InteractionType="N">
<User>
<LoginName>SWONG00</LoginName>
<FirstName>STEPHEN</FirstName>
<LastName>WONG</LastName>
<UUID>4397109</UUID>
<FirmNumber>13133</FirmNumber>
<AccountNumber>231115</AccountNumber>
<CompanyName>DBS BANK LIMITED HON</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>SWONG00@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress>STEPHENWONGWE@DBS.COM</CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>04/01/2016 01:31:29</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459474289</DateTimeUTC>
<Content>
ajdslsahdsj;a
</Content>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</Message>
<Message InteractionType="N" DeviceType="M">
<User>
<LoginName>FCHAN95</LoginName>
<FirstName>FLORENCE</FirstName>
<LastName>CHAN</LastName>
<CompanyName>GOLDMAN SACHS (ASIA)</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>FCHAN95@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress></CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>04/01/2016 02:49:46</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459478986</DateTimeUTC>
<Content>
sagdkjsagdkjashdlasjd
</Content>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</Message>
<Message InteractionType="N" DeviceType="M">
<User>
<LoginName>FCHAN95</LoginName>
<FirstName>FLORENCE</FirstName>
<LastName>CHAN</LastName>
<CompanyName>GOLDMAN SACHS (ASIA)</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>FCHAN95@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress></CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>04/01/2016 02:49:46</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459478986</DateTimeUTC>
<Content>
jsdhkshdksjdlsjdlks
</Content>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</Message>
<Message InteractionType="N" DeviceType="M">
<User>
<LoginName>FCHAN95</LoginName>
<FirstName>FLORENCE</FirstName>
<LastName>CHAN</LastName>
<CompanyName>GOLDMAN SACHS (ASIA)</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>FCHAN95@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress></CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>04/01/2016 03:47:37</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459482457</DateTimeUTC>
<Content>
jshdkshdksjdlskld
</Content>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</Message>
<Message InteractionType="N" DeviceType="M">
<User>
<LoginName>FCHAN95</LoginName>
<FirstName>FLORENCE</FirstName>
<LastName>CHAN</LastName>
<CompanyName>GOLDMAN SACHS (ASIA)</CompanyName>
<EmailAddress>FCHAN95@Bloomberg.net</EmailAddress>
<CorporateEmailAddress></CorporateEmailAddress>
</User>
<DateTime>04/01/2016 03:47:37</DateTime>
<DateTimeUTC>1459482457</DateTimeUTC>
<Content>
aasasasasas
</Content>
<ConversationID>PCHAT-0x3000001CA8361</ConversationID>
</Message>
<EndTime>04/01/2016 03:47:37</EndTime>
<EndTimeUTC>1459482457</EndTimeUTC>
</Conversation>
</FileDump>
```

Comment: changed input file and few changes required pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text from all the "Content", "LoginName" and "ConversationID" nodes can fit into memory, then the solution might be like the one I'm posting below (reads from `input.xml`, writes to `output.txt`; also, I assume that you want your lines numbered 1, 2, ... and you want the "+" sign to separate data from different messages as you specified in the question).

If, however, that data can't fit into memory, then you will for example need to extract it with StAX in the format (ConversationID, LoginName, Content) into a file, then sort it [in external memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) (on disk or on multiple machines), then merge sequential lines with the same ConversationID. Or just split the initial XML into several, process each of them using the following, then you will still need to merge resulting files but that might be easier.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class Solution {

    private static final String ROOM_ID = "RoomID";
    private static final String CONTENT = "Content";
    private static final String LOGIN_NAME = "LoginName";
    private static final String CONVERSATION_ID = "ConversationID";
    private static final String FILE_DUMP = "FileDump";
    private static final String MESSAGE = "Message";
    private static final String CONVERSATION = "Conversation";
    private static final String START_TIME = "StartTime";

    static class ConversationInfo {
        private String startTimeStr;

        private String conversationId;

        private final Set<String> users = new HashSet<>();

        private final List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%s %s (%d) %s", startTimeStr, conversationId, users.size(),
                 StringUtils.join(messages, " + "));
        }
    }

    static class Message {

        public final String userName;

        public final String content;

        public Message(String name, String content) {
            this.userName = name;
            this.content = content;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return userName + " " + content;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws XMLStreamException, IOException {
        XMLInputFactory xf = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        List<ConversationInfo> m = new ArrayList<>();
        try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("input.xml")) {
            XMLStreamReader xr = xf.createXMLStreamReader(fin);
            LOOP: while (xr.hasNext()) {
                int event = xr.next();
                switch (event) {
                    case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT: {
                        String elName = xr.getLocalName();
                        if (CONVERSATION.equals(elName)) {
                            ConversationInfo convInfo = parseConversation(xr);
                            if (convInfo != null) {
                                m.add(convInfo);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT: {
                        String elName = xr.getLocalName();
                        if (FILE_DUMP.equals(elName)) {
                            break LOOP;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT:
                        throw new IllegalStateException("xml not well-formed: <"
                            + FILE_DUMP + "> tag not closed");
                }
            }
        }
        try (FileWriter w = new FileWriter("output.txt")) {
            int i = 1;
            for (ConversationInfo convInfo : m) {
                w.write(String.format("%d %s\n", i++, convInfo));
            }
        }
    }

    private static ConversationInfo parseConversation(XMLStreamReader xr)
            throws XMLStreamException {
        ConversationInfo convInfo = new ConversationInfo();
        while (xr.hasNext()) {
            int event = xr.next();
            switch (event) {
                case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT: {
                    String elName = xr.getLocalName();
                    if (MESSAGE.equals(elName)) {
                        Message message = parseMessage(xr);
                        if (message != null) {
                            convInfo.messages.add(message);
                            convInfo.users.add(message.userName);
                        }
                    } else if (START_TIME.equals(elName)) {
                        convInfo.startTimeStr = xr.getElementText();
                    } else if (ROOM_ID.equals(elName)) {
                        convInfo.conversationId = xr.getElementText();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT: {
                    String elName = xr.getLocalName();
                    if (CONVERSATION.equals(elName)) {
                        return convInfo;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT:
                    throw new XMLStreamException("xml not well-formed: <"
                        + CONVERSATION + "> tag not closed");
            }
        }
        throw new XMLStreamException(
            "unexpected end of xml file while parsing a conversation");
    }

    private static Message parseMessage(XMLStreamReader xr)
            throws XMLStreamException {
        String userName = null;
        String content = null;
        while (xr.hasNext()) {
            int event = xr.next();
            switch (event) {
                case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT: {
                    String elName = xr.getLocalName();
                    if (LOGIN_NAME.equals(elName)) {
                        userName = xr.getElementText();
                    } else if (CONTENT.equals(elName)) {
                        content = StringUtils.trimToEmpty(xr.getElementText());
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT: {
                    String elName = xr.getLocalName();
                    if (MESSAGE.equals(elName)) {
                        return new Message(userName, content);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT:
                    throw new XMLStreamException("xml not well-formed: <"
                        + MESSAGE + "> tag not closed");
            }
        }
        throw new XMLStreamException(
            "unexpected end of xml file while parsing a message");
    }
}
```

Comment: Multimap is from the Guava library, the latest version of which as of now is 19

Comment: I updated the solution so that is doesn't use Multimap and Guava at all

Comment: I have questions about data relations in this XML. 1) can we assume all messages (what's inside <Message>...</Message>) inside a Conversation (<Conversation>...</Conversation>) belong to that conversation only? 2) can we assume ConversationID of a message nested inside a conversation equals to its RoomID? 3) can we assume there are no Conversations with duplicate RoomID in the file?

Comment: I want to add one more info to file like user and how many messages they sent. this should be after conversationID print.. like user NMA40(1)***TAYB(1)***WAU(1) .... then as usual it follows content and count as is....          if in some file NMA40 may send 2 messages then it will be NMA40(2). Please help me to add

Comment: Also I found in my real input file that ROOM ID is not unique .. as it is daily data some chats may longer for 3 days so in some files the same ROOMID is repeated.. so code should not consider ROOMID as unique if new <Conversation> started then just rint a new line with new sequenceID or index number with dateTime,ID,numOfuser content, etc...

Comment: hi, I have changed input file with some user have left 2 times messages so output file should print FCHAN95(6)***G_LO(1)***WVU(1)***SWONG00(1)...like on...